# Configure symfony not to consider subfolder as part of the route

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7.1

I have an apache server and my projects are inside `/var/www/html/`

Inside there I created a new project using composer like `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton myproject`.

Then inside my project I ran the command `composer require symfony/apache-pack` which added an .htaccess file inside `public` folder containing the default `.htaccess` of symfony.

When I accessed my server like `http://192.168.0.2/myproject` I got the folder list that apache serves if it doesn't find an `index.php` file because it accessed the default symfony folder in `/var/www/html/myproject` and not the public folder.

So inside the folder `/var/www/html/myproject` which is a symfony project I added the following .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /myproject/

    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

No I when I visit `http://192.168.0.2/myproject` I get an error that `No route found for "GET /myproject/"` which means that symfony now considers `/myproject` as part of a route.

Is there a solution for this. I suggested solution that I got from symfony slack would be to have the project inside another folder and symlink only the public folder.

Something like:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    59 gmponos  9 19:26 myproject -> /home/gmponos/Projects/myproject/public/`

This is a solution but I really need to have the whole project under `/var/www/html/` and not symlink the public folder.

Also another solution according to the official documentation is editing the apache config and change the document root from /var/www/html/myproject to /var/www/html/myproject/public but I need the configuration to stay inside the project and not change the apache config.

Is there any solution?

Comment: You can go into your apache configuration and change the document root from /var/www/html/myproject to /var/www/html/myproject/public.  I suppose you could also research how to add a .htaccess file to myproject with deny all permissions.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned above that editing the apache conf is not a solution.

Comment: Updated the question above.

Comment: "I really need to have the whole project under /var/www/html/" Could you explain why? Having the source code in a web-accessible folder is usually regarded a security risk. Someone might be able to access your code and exploit an issue exposed by it or get access to your configuration and then for example mess with your database.

Comment: This will happens only for dev reasons and not on production. No it's hard for me to explain why. The case is as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution?
>   No Solution for what you are requesting :

1. You must have the rights to configure Apache to adjust the document root to either :

   - /var/www/html/myproject,
   - or /var/www/html/myproject/public 
     and set according access permissions in apache config file
2. Putting whole code in code in /var/www/html directory, and give free remote access through Web (Apache) is very risky, for production environments.